# Simultaneously Output and show the result in R

Tags: r, export-to-excel

I'm wondering if it would be possible to both show a `cat(...)` in the **console (Rstudio)** **"AND ALSO"** save the file in **`.txt` format**?

**Here is my R code:**

```
   SOS = 33
    df = 12

  cat("\n","-------------", "\n" ,"SOS  ","  df","\n", "-------------","\n",
       SOS,"    ",df,"\n", "-------------", file = "Output.txt" )
```

Comment: `double.cat = function(..., file) {do.call(cat, list(...)); do.call(cat, c(list(...), file = file))}`

Comment: I use `sink` to print the console output into a file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SOS = 33
df = 12

#prepare your output
x = paste("\n","-------------", "\n" ,"SOS "," df","\n", "-------------","\n",
                                    SOS," ",df,"\n", "-------------", sep = "")

#display in console
cat(x)
#-------------
#SOS  df
#-------------
#33 12
#-------------

#Write to a txt file
cat(x, file = "output.txt")
```